# During adding new View ,I got "The resource cannot be found"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, view

During adding new View I got this error:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> The resource cannot be found.
>
> Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its
>   dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is
>   temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make
>   sure that it is spelled correctly.
>
> Requested URL: /Payment/Index

Here is my controller:

```
public class PaymentController : Controller
{

public ActionResult Index()
{
        return View();
}
}
```

Here is value of index.cshtml

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Company/Login.cshtml";
}

<h2>This is the second Page</h2>
```

I can't understand why I get Error

Comment: You have to add your new routes in RouteConfig.cs. Or, if you are using Attribute Routing, you have to add your route values at the top of the actions.

Comment: No , I didn't do that , How should I can ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You  might want to check the route.config  file

```
 routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

see this url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}".

This is the name how your URL appears.

Comment: You are fantastic :)

Comment: "{culture}/{controller}/{action}/{id}"

Comment: @ara are you using the language pack?

Comment: @ara glad you made it.

Answer (score 0):

You got to check the route config which is under the App_Start.. If you want the PaymentController's Index page as your start up page then you must go there and change..

**defaults:  new { controller = "Payment", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }**

Comment: I don't want to change Home page, I just wanted to add new View

Comment: Did you check the folder structure where your Payment's Index page is.. Your Index page should be under the Views->Payment->Index.. Possibilities of getting that error because of that improper structure too..